# C# Remove Component By Name

Tags: c#

Well, I'm creating a method able to remove a component from a panel according to its name and its type. My code is currently:

```
private void RemoveItemByName<T>(Panel panel, string name)
{
    foreach (T item in panel.Controls.OfType<T>().Where(item => item.Name == name))
        panel.Controls.Remove(item);
}
```

But the property `Name` doesn't exist in type `T` because `T` didn't be defined yet. I want to use it this way:

```
RemoveItemByName<TextBox>(pnlMain, "txtPesquisa");
RemoveItemByName<Button>(pnlMain, "btnCloseSearch");
```

In this case, the compiler gives me two errors:
`Cannot resolve symbol 'Name' in item` and
`Argument type 'T' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'`

When I try to cast T to the accepted type it doesn't allow me to do. How can I do this conversion in way that this work in this way?

Comment: What is the purpose of using Generics here? They all inherit from Control.

Comment: Because I want to pass the type of the component to get better performance. This is because I have `.OfType<T>`. I'll search ONLY in components of the SPECIFIC type.

Comment: @MikeCheel He wants to remove items of type `T`, not all controls.

Comment: He is removing by Name though. Names are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to give `T` a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) so the compiler knows what methods and properties are available on the type:

```
private void RemoveItemByName<T>(Panel panel, string name) 
  where T : System.Windows.Control
{
    foreach (T item in panel.Controls.OfType<T>().ToList().Where(
     item => item.Name == name))
          panel.Controls.Remove(item);
}
```

This will tell the compiler any object of type `Control` (including objects that inherit from it) can be passed
 in to the method.

Comment: You copied a bug from the OP's snippet, it is not legal to modify a collection while iterating it.  A copy of the collection is required to avoid the damage, add ToList().